# Python requests ротирующиеся данные?

Tags: python, requests, discord

Возможно название темы не совсем раскрыла суть вопроса, так что сделаю это тут.

```
import time
import requests
file = open('foo.txt', encoding='utf-8')

#HEADERS
    #4get
header1 = {
     'Authorization': 'TOKEN'
}
    #clinger
header2 = {
     'Authorization': 'TOKEN'
}

#PAYLOADS

payload = {
    'content': file.readline()
}
payload2 = {
    'content': file1.readline()
}
#data и headers должны меняться в цикле
r = requests.post("https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/ChannelID/messages", data=payloadX, headers=headerX) 
time.sleep(2)
```

Пытаюсь сделать автоотправку сообщений в дискорде, но не понимаю как сделать изменяемые данные. (могу ошибаться) Насколько я знаю requests принимает в параметры data, headers только словари, а словари насколько мне известно это неупорядоченные данные. я пробовал делать цикл, но не смог итерироваться по словарям, как я понял, как раз изза того что они неупорядочены.

Пробовал пойти напролом и конечно это работало, если создать десяток хэдеров и пару сотен пейлоадов, но даже мне как новичку в языке больно смотреть на этот говнокод.

Отчаившись, я задался вопросом, возможно ли вовсе сделать этот проект?

Очень рассчитываю на помощь знающих людей, возможно не четко объяснил смысл, готов ответить на все вопросы в комментариях

Comment: А почему не пройтись циклом сделать словарь конфига и циклом по нему.

Comment: я дилетант в этом вопросе, можете рассказать подробней о том что это и как сделать?

Comment: код кинул ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
import requests

df = {'Headers':[{'Authorization': 'TOKEN'},{'Authorization':'TOKEN2'}]}


for i in df['Headers']:
    with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f:
        file = f.read().splitlines()
    for b in file:
        
        r=requests.post("https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/ChannelID/messages", data=b, headers=i)
        
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: вы очень приблизили меня к ответу, за это огромное спасибо, но у меня суть задачи такая -
есть файл, допустим на 100+ строк
и некоторое количество токенов аккаунтов, допустим от 2 до 20
как сделать так что бы цикл оканчивался, когда закончатся строки в текстовике, а не когда каждый аккаунт отправит по одному сообщению? еще раз большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Я провильно понял вам нужно чтоб каждій из токенов попробовал отправить все строки из файла?

Comment: df = {'Headers':[{'Authorization': 'TOKEN'},{'Authorization':'TOKEN2'}]}


for i in df['Headers']:
    with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f:
        file = f.read().splitlines()
    for b in file:
        
        r=requests.post("https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/ChannelID/messages", data=b, headers=i)
        
        time.sleep(2)

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось, невероятно выручили!